# Вылетает QWebEngineView

Tags: c++, qt

Здравствуйте. Пишу небольшой клиент вк и мне надо для авторизации открыть сайт для подтверждения. Программа работала отлично, потом начала вылетать. Выследив, на каком месте оно вылетает, я понял, что это:

```
LoginWidget::LoginWidget(const QUrl &url, QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    QWebEngineView *view = new QWebEngineView(this);
    view->load(url);
```

Без этого фрагмента, программа открывается, но не загружает браузер (что вполне логично). Странно то, что это встречается в Debug, в Release всё работает нормально. И да, под линуксом всё тоже работает отлично, как в Release, так и в Debug. В выводе есть странные ошибки( иногда ссылаются на несуществующие пути): http://pastebin.com/NBycjh20

Кратко, как работает программа(выложить всю программу не могу, не поместится) : Есть класс для авторизации, он принимает код приложения, формирует url для авторизации, принимает токен с браузера и т.д. Мы создаем ссылку на обьект класса с этим браузером, и открываем его. Вызываем connect для обработки сигнала слотом и класса авторизации.

```
LoginWidget *wgt = new LoginWidget(url);
connect(wgt, SIGNAL(authorized(QString,QString,QString)), SLOT(tokenReceived(QString,QString,QString)));
wgt->exec();
```

И всё. Надеюсь, нормально обьяснил, но я могу и предоставить ссылку на гитхаб с проектом, если потребуется. Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 0):

Виджет `QWebEngineView` нужно "положить" на `LoginWidget`, как пример, вот так:

```
LoginWidget::LoginWidget(const QUrl &url, QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    QWebEngineView *view = new QWebEngineView();
    QVBoxLayout *L = new QVBoxLayout();
    L->addWidget(view);
    setLayout(L);
    view->load(url);
```

Проверить возможности нет, проверяйте у себя.

Comment: Не работает. Хотя у меня до этого было в QGridLayout (забыл упомянуть).